# Need an alternative to OReplace in Tearadata SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, replace, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need an alternative to Teradata's function "OReplace". I work at a company in which the DBA won't give analysts access to execute the function in their SQL scripts. For example, what would the SQL equivalent be of ...

```
SELECT OReplace('Hello World!','!','')
```

Comment: I would probably connect with Excel to that DB and do processing in Excel. [Connect Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel) I bet there is ODBC connector to Terradata.

Comment: Or even better using PowerQuery: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-Teradata-database-Power-Query-ddd537df-0c2c-49f2-92a0-bc66888ed65b Then you have all power of Excel fucntions/PIVOT table/M language and so on

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @lad2025, unfortunately, the current dataset we are looking into is in excess of 10M rows. Excel probably won't be a great solution for us

Comment: PowerQuery can handle it. But the final result should be filtered/aggregatd so it could fit worksheet. https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/ms-excel/analyzing-50-million-records-excel/. Still you should only get data that you really need so filter and do not use `SELECT *` to avoid excessive network traffic.

Comment: No `oReplace`? It's builtin since TD14(13.10?), you must be running an ancient version of Teradata, what is returned for `select databasename, functionname from dbc.functionsV where functionname like 'OReplace%'`?

Comment: @dnoeth we are running TD15. if we were to run the statement w/ oreplace we get an error like "user does not have execute function access to syslib.oreplace2". When asking DBA for permissions he's stated that he will not give it. I don't know man, i don't make the rules! lol

Comment: No way to restrict you from using the builtin `oReplace`, even a DBA can't on TD15 :-) Public has access rights to the functions in `td_sysfnlib`, but there's an old version of this UDF in `syslib`, which comes before `td_sysfnlib` in the search path. Simply qualify the function: `td_sysfnlib.OReplace('Hello World!','!','')` (and talk to your DBA, if the old one can be dropped?)

Comment: @dnoeth, thank you! qualifying did allow us to execute. very much appreciated!

Comment: And don't forget to send your dba a note - "I did it anyway".